# How can I make an animated screen for an iPad?

Tags: animation

I am trying to make a concept video for the apple pencil. I want to add shots of it drawing on an iPad but I am not sure how to make it. How would I make an iPad screen the shows where the pen drew? Any help or references would be much appreciated.

Comment: would Dynamic Paint be an option?

Comment: a link to an animation or image how it should look like would improve your question as well....

Comment: It might be simpler to do this 'backwards' .. i.e. drive the location of the pen with the end of the stroke it's just 'drawn'.  But, as @Chris says, just show us a sketch of the desired result, so we don't go down the wrong rabbit-hole .. :)